# Pyenv broke after upgrading to Big Sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, zsh, pyenv

Pyenv has not worked since upgrading to Big Sur. This is how it started:

```
❯ pyenv install 3.8.0
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.0...
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/_y/vdsjczjj3nvflspjcl8r68zr0000gq/T/python-build.20210131003659.3456
Results logged to /var/folders/_y/vdsjczjj3nvflspjcl8r68zr0000gq/T/python-build.20210131003659.3456.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for python3.8... python3.8
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/_y/vdsjczjj3nvflspjcl8r68zr0000gq/T/python-build.20210131003659.3456/Python-3.8.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

So I ran `xcode-select --install`. It went through, though I don't see a xrun directory under `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/`.

I read many different github issues' pages, StackOverflow posts, and tried many different things including `brew install zlib sqlite bzip2 libiconv libzip`. This is where I am right now:

```
❯ pyenv install 3.8.0
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.0...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/_y/vdsjczjj3nvflspjcl8r68zr0000gq/T/python-build.20210201012936.8553
Results logged to /var/folders/_y/vdsjczjj3nvflspjcl8r68zr0000gq/T/python-build.20210201012936.8553.log

Last 10 log lines:
              ^
clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -L brew --prefix bzip2/include  -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -L /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -L brew --prefix bzip2/include  -std=c99 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration  -I./Include/internal  -I. -I./Include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/rayhanmuktader/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/include  -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/rayhanmuktader/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE_BUILTIN  -c ./Modules/pwdmodule.c -o Modules/pwdmodule.o
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Lbrew' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
c
lang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Lbrew' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
1 error generated.
make: *** [Modules/posixmodule.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 warning generated.
```

My `.zshrc` looks this at the moment:

```
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"


export LDFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/lib -L brew --prefix bzip2/lib"
export CFLAGS="-L $(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include -L brew --prefix bzip2/include"
```

I also tried `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1 pyenv install 3.8.0` but that didn't solve it either. If it helps anything, note that it hangs for an unusually long time at `python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk` line.

Thank you if read this far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This worked for me: https://dev.to/lgw4/getting-pyenv-and-friends-working-on-macos-big-sur-1k5l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me (kind of).
I followed step 1 and step 2 from https://koji-kanao.medium.com/install-python-3-8-0-via-pyenv-on-bigsur-b4246987a548
I upgraded to BigSur 11.2, installed XCode 12.5 beta from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/resources/. I also installed Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.5 beta from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools (I don't know if this was necessary)

My .zshrc looks like this:

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"
```

Then in order to install python 3.8.0 I ran:
`$ CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include -I$(brew --prefix bzip2)/include -I$(brew --prefix readline)/include -I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include" LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib -L$(brew --prefix readline)/lib -L$(brew --prefix zlib)/lib -L$(brew --prefix bzip2)/lib" pyenv install --patch 3.8.0 < <(curl -sSL https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/8ea6353.patch\?full_index\=1)`

This actually installed it. HOWEVER, when I ran poetry install on an existing project, it started installing the package then it suddenly blew up with the following error:

• Installing pynacl (1.3.0): Failed

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyNaCl
Failed to build PyNaCl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyNaCl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.2; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/rayhanmuktader/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/desk-backend-kAA1Wc9W-py3.8/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.


at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/utils/env.py:1074 in _run
    1070│                 output = subprocess.check_output(
    1071│                     cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, **kwargs
    1072│                 )
    1073│         except CalledProcessError as e:
  → 1074│             raise EnvCommandError(e, input=input_)
    1075│
    1076│         return decode(output)
    1077│
    1078│     def execute(self, bin, *args, **kwargs):
```

The solution to this problem was running `$ /Users/rayhanmuktader/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/desk-backend-kAA1Wc9W-py3.8/bin/python -m pip install pynacl==1.3.0` to install the pynacl package. Then running `poetry install` again to continue the installation process. Rinse and repeat for every package it fails to install through `poetry install`.